# How to edit ID3 tags on iPod without iTunes

Tags: itunes, music, ipod, id3-tag

I have an iPod Touch, that I used to manage with iTunes on Windows, but now I'm using a Mac (with MacOS Sonoma).

I noticed that iTunes is no more, for which I won't shed a single tear. However I would like to edit some of the ID3 tags (on the iPod itself), and I am simply not able figure out how to do it. I remember doing that via iTunes many times.

If I open the Music app, and select any of the tracks, the options in the menu bar are greyed out. I can't play music either (not that I wanted to). Using the file browser I can get only a rudimentary song list, with an option to delete the file.

What am I missing? Do I have any option to edit the tags in-place without installing iTunes on some hacky way?

Comment: It's not iTunes/Music, it's that the iPod isn't linked to that music library (on the Mac running Sonoma).

Comment: Okay.... any advice where should I click to make this state change?

Comment: I noticed that my Mac wasn't "authorized", as for some reason it doesn't show an error upon sign-in problems (maybe I miss iTunes a bit). Anyway, even after successful authorization unfortunately there is no change, pretty much every option is disabled. (Though I can move music from/to the iPod without problem)

Comment: "Authorized" refers to the ability to play protected tracks via that particular Mac, there is a limit of five devices.  Regarding being able to to move to/from, I will step back, you should never be able to pull tracks OFF the iPod, and putting tracks onto it always required the device to be paired with a particular library.  So something else is going on.

Comment: `you should never be able to pull tracks OFF the iPod` haha, what? Of course you can remove music from iPods. Although it would be *very* Apple-like, we are not there yet

Comment: Of course you can, but not arbitrarily.  It was always that you could not sync back from the iPod to an arbitrary Mac.  There used to be a whole cottage industry devoted to utilities that would allow you to copy the other way.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are getting *way* derailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" was installing iTunes inside Windows inside VirtualBox.